# Is there a way to "tag","flag" or to "label" a folder on the eclipse navigator panel?

Tags: eclipse, tagging

I was thinking if there's a way to tag a folder on eclipse with a color, kinda like if you were using a highlighter pen. I have many folders on a project but i use 3 of them more constantly then i use the others, so if they were marked with different colors i'd speed up my productivity, because i wouldn't waste too much time looking for the folders.

**Edit:**
I just found out about the working sets. Even though that's not what i was originally thinking about, it does the trick. Feel free to answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is probably to add those folders to a separate [working set](http://blog.alagad.com/2007/10/29/using-eclipse-working-sets-instead-of-workspaces/), and in the package explorer view use working sets as top level elements (configure that via the little triangle at the top of the package explorer).

Comment: The working sets as top level elements are nice. Now i want to highlight it with colors. For example: images folder is blue, css folder is red, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use Mylyn, which is set of plugins designed to help you narrow your focus around a specific task. Mylyn will track what resources you've accessed during the course of working on a task and de-emphasize all others visually. You control when a task starts and stops. You can have multiple tasks going in parallel and switch between them. The visual context will switch accordingly. Mylyn also has integration with many bug tracking systems, so if your system is supported, Mylyn can use bugs as tasks.

Comment: I've seen Mylyn standing there, all quiet, but never messed with it. I'll try. :)